# Rails System Testing, no selector available for assert_selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I am getting into rails system testing and trying to use assert_selector to find an edited text. Here is the problem, the text is not wrapped in a CSS selector, it is just plain text on the page (please check the screenshot).

[image]

Is there a better assertion to find the edited text on the page, or is my page just poorly optimized because the content is not wrapped in a CSS selector?

Surely there is a way to still search the page and find this edited text?

Comment: I would say "poorly optimized" for testability... easy to fix though!

Comment: Are you just trying to make sure that text is on the page? if so then `has_xpath?("//div/text()[contains(.,'front end')]")` should work for you. If you wanted to be even more specific: `"//div/strong[contains(text(),'Title')]/following-sibling::text()[1][contains(.,'front end')]"`

Comment: Yeah! I just want to find it on the page and the has_xpath solution passed!!! Thanks so much guys, I will keep optimization in mind for future projects